# How to use GPU to detect object using pre-trained models in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm using Tensorflow to detect object based on [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) tutorial. The reason why it's running so slow is this line `output_dict =sess.run(tensor_dict,
                                 feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})`. And below is the whole function code:

```
def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
with graph.as_default():
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    print('GPU is using')
    with tf.Session() as sess:

      time0 = datetime.datetime.now()                  

      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)

      time1 = datetime.datetime.now()               

      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        # The following processing is only for single image
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      time2 = datetime.datetime.now()                 

      # Run inference
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
      time3 = datetime.datetime.now()      
      # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
          'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
      if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]

      time4 = datetime.datetime.now()         

print(time1-time0, time2-time1, time3-time2, time4-time3)
return output_dict
```

I don't know how to use GPU with tf.session.run(). Anyone can teach me how to use GPU with session.run???

Comment: Are you sure you have installed tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: I'm sure I had installed tensorflow-gpu,  it output GPU is using.
But I don't know how to use it to detect objects in image. More than 3s for each image with Powerful GPU is unacceptable...

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Can you follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage) and then tell me if it says GPU is being used during prediction task

Comment: I run `nvidia-smi --loop=1` and `nvidia-smi`, but I'm using Docker and maybe other people are using cards also. 
Do you know any command that can tell me exactly whether my Python program is using GPU to detect objects or not?

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf \n
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name() \n
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0': \n
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found') \n
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))` Since I cannot use enter to differntiate, I have used \n to indicate that you need to type that at the next line

Comment: I've edited my question. Can you tell me how to use GPU with tf.session.run()?

Comment: rather than using feeddict, use `tf.dataset()` api. that Improves the performance, basically after the dataset api, we rarely use feed dict, as dataset api can directly load data into GPU memory

Comment: Great idea. But can you explain more clearly how to use `tf.dataset()` instead of `feed_dict`. I'm searching in the Internet but it's a bit slow....

Comment: Let me know if you are able to follow [this](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/18_TFRecords_Dataset_API.ipynb), there is also an accompanying YouTube video explaining this, if you face problems still, point to your specific problem and I will see what I can do.